# What is the difference between forceFocus() and setFocus() in SWT?

Tags: swt

I don't quite understand the difference between these two methods.  In what situation would `forceFocus()` be better than `setFocus()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to ***SWT: The Standard Widget Toolkit, Volume 1***, forceFocus():

> Forces the control to receive keyboard
>   events. Controls that do not normally
>   accept keyboard input will take focus
>   using this method. If focus cannot be
>   assigned for any reason, false is
>   returned.

also:

> Generally speaking, forcing focus is
>   something that you never want to do.
>   For example, forcing focus to a label
>   is not very useful because labels
>   don't draw in a manner that indicates
>   they can accept input. Forcing focus
>   to a control that does not expect it
>   can confuse users because they have no
>   idea where their keystrokes are going.
>   Application programs should always use
>   setFocus() to assign focus.

Answer (score 4):

Coming in way late on this one, but I just finished a prolonged head-beating-against-wall session on something related to this and thought I'd do a quick report:

If your control has children, the `setFocus(myControl)` will do a depth-first search down the child tree and set focus to the lowest first child.  On the other hand, `forceFocus(myControl)` will just set focus to myControl and have done with it.

I had a situation with a modeless dialog with a GridLayout, where most of the grid cells were a set of Canvas subclassed objects that needed focus.  (Yes, this is a bit odd, but I wanted to be able to hover over a cell and type stuff into it.)  The last control in the grid was a "done" button, which I set as the default selection.

When the mouse left the canvas cells, I was doing a `setFocus(myDialogShell)`, which instantly set focus to the first canvas element, preventing the "done" button from receiving the \r and disposing of the whole sordid business.  On the other hand, `forceFocus(myDialogShell)` did the trick.